# In what case can the object be placed at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: word-order, direct-objects

> Every word I say is true; this I promise you.

I think the pronoun 'this' is the direct object of the verb 'promise' and 'this' should be  be placed after 'you', but it is placed at the beginning of the sentence.

Because this sentence is on a [web page](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/what-is-a-verb.html) about English grammar at http://grammar.yourdictionary.com , I believe this is not grammatically wrong.
Is this an exception? Then, how can it?

Comment: English is liberal in its word order which, as in the case you cite, offers alternative emphases and nuances to expressions. That much, I promise you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done for emphasis, and linguists call it '[fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_clause_syntax#Fronting_and_zeroing)'