# English syntax: Object at the beginning of a sentence / Object as sentence opening

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to build an English sentence as follows, with the object as opener?

- *The red chair we placed at the left end of the table.*

(instead of the 'standard' syntax: *We placed the red chair at the left end of the table.*)

We (in Germany) learned that syntax in English is very strict. Subsequently, we learned:

**never**(?) begin a sentence with the object!

This seems obvious to me for sentences such as "The child caught the ball.", as "The ball caught the child." is not really helpful of course.

But in my example, I can't see any potential misunderstanding, and, by my 'feeling', it sounds to be reasonable English. Unfortunately I could not find any posts that support my hunch.
So, could anybody of you native speakers or English-experts give me advice, please?

If my example should be a viable option, I have a subsequent question: Would I need to insert a comma after the object?

- *The red chair, we placed at the left end of the table.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what case can the object be placed at the beginning of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229177/in-what-case-can-the-object-be-placed-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence)

Comment: The technical term for this kind of fronting is [_Topicalization_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization). Another name is Y-Movement, where "Y" stands for Yiddish, since this kind of fronting was very prominent in Yiddish-speakers' English. The archetypal Y-Movement sentence, from McCawley, is _Egg creams you want, bananas you'll get._

Comment: Yes, and topicalization is fine *as long as* the object of the verb does not fall between the subject of the sentence and the verb. This is in fact the effective difference between the example sentences given in the question and is the source of chaos in sentences which attempt such a construction. That is, it's obvious in the first sentence that WE moved the chair, while in the second, it's not so obvious who caught the ball. Try instead, "The ball the child caught," and bam, you're back on track, though maybe intruding on the lands of the odd.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133886/discussion-on-question-by-jaysigg-english-syntax-object-at-the-beginning-of-a-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences such as *"The red chair we placed at the left end of the table"* can only be sensibly analysed in their context. Several of the comments under your question have correctly noted that the sentence is comprehensible and grammatical in certain contexts.

For example, a context in which the interlocutors are talking about the relocation of furniture in a room and wish to focus special attention on the relocation of the chairs of different colours.

Radford, in *Analysing English Sentences* (p36-38), discusses one aspect of sentence structure that is relevant to your question: the relative position of  heads and complements.

(All bold words below are bold in the original.)

> In English all heads (nouns, verbs, prepositions, adjectives, etc.)
> immediately precede their complements. In informal-terms we can say
> that English is a **head-first** language.

Radford notes that Korean, conversely, is a **head-last** language. And further:

> ...it is clear that the relative positioning of heads with respect to
> their complements is one word-order parameter along which languages
> differ; the relevant parameter can be termed the **Head-Position
> Parameter/HPP**.

Radford then goes on to note;

> ...the Head Position Parameter specifies the **default** ordering of
> particular kinds of heads with respect to their complements -- i.e.
> the ordering we use by default ...for a head which is not marked as
> exceptional in its lexical entry.

And later:

> ... the  way it (the HPP) is set...determines the canonical (i.e.
> 'normal', 'basic' or 'unmarked') word order in a language. However,
> this canonical order can be disrupted by movement operations, as
> illustrated in the contrast below:
>
> - (49) (a) I can't **stand** *cabbage*
> - (b) *Cabbage*, I can't **stand**
>
> ...in 48(b), the complement *cabbage* has been moved to the front of the
> sentence in order to highlight it, with the result that the
> bold-printed verb no longer precedes its italicised complement.

This specific word movement is usually called *fronting* and serves to make, in this case, *cabbage* the *topic* of sentence (b) - in a discourse feature called *topicalization*.

As to your subsequent question, I would omit the comma in the *cabbage* and *red chair* examples. But in examples of fronting with a resumptive pronoun, the comma is needed:

- The red chair, I put *it* at the left end of the table.

Comment: If someone perversely wants to front a heavy object we'd benefit from a comma. 'The red chair we had placed at the right end of the table last time we brought in the extra chairs from the kitchen, we placed at the left end of the table.'

Comment: @Edwin. Right. And if we were moving sofas not chairs, we would have an even heavier object.

Comment: I think I need a psychiatrist's couch.